# How to set cookie from browser URL field, without navigating to Search Engine

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I have 1 task to perform, where I need to set value for a cookie from browser URL

1: Got to : http://12.122.225.126:6300

2: Set to the broser url field
javascript:document.cookie="Name=generatedValue"

Can you please suggest How can I perform the second step? when I am trying to paste javascript content on my Browser URL, it is navigating to search engine,

Answer (score 0):

To prevent outside attacks most browsers will not allow you to paste `javascript:` but as long as you write that part yourself you can paste `document.cookie="Name=generatedValue"` just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but this always navigates me to google search(In Chrome browser).

Answer (score 0):

While pasting JWT in Browser URL, "javascript:" was always missed while pasting which was the reason it directed to chrome search, "javascript:" required to be pasted explicitly,